# Gaussian Software Package: #2070 error (maybe on link0)

Tags: computational-chemistry, molecular-modeling, gaussian

I have a computer equipped with two Intel Xeon cpus(6 core @2.67GHz each) and 64GB RAM.

I think there is no problem in my gaussian input file except for link0 section. I selected 6 cores and 10GB ram. I guessed it is quite doable for my pc. But Gaussian 09W gave me the "link died"(#2070). The reason why I am pretty sure there is no problem on other section is computation works well if I choose 1GB ram and 1 core.

Do you have an idea to select link0 (mem and cpu core) properly?

Comment: The question cannot be answered unless you upload the complete input file and the output file, because almost all error aborts (not only memory shortage but also input file syntax error, incompatible input options, convergence failure, or even software bugs...) of Gaussian report the error code #2070 on Windows. It's very misleading that Gaussian reports an error code that carries almost no information, but anyway that's what the Gaussian developers chose to do...

Comment: Firstly, check your version of Gaussian (usually in the first 100 lines of output file). For me, it is a string 'ES64L-G16RevC.01'. If your version is IA32W, it means that you are using a 32-bit Windows Gaussian, which has the restriction that at most 4 cores and ~1400MB memory. Secondly, better upload your input and output files (you should show at least the last few lines of output file)

Comment: Thank you @wzkchem5 and jxzou for helping me.  I am sorry to forget uploading input and output file. I will edit my question and upload the files as soon as possible to make things clear for future readers. Thank you so much for your time and have a nice weekend. :)

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but now that it has been more than 1 year, can you update us please? Are you still urgently or actively in need of an answer to this question? Did you figure it out? **In your last comment you said that you would edit your question, but that did not happen**.